# Why is Firefox so slow over SSH?

Tags: ssh, firefox

I try to launch Firefox over SSH, using

```
ssh -X user@hostname
```

and then

```
firefox -no-remote
```

but it's very very slow.

How can I fix this? Is it a connection problem?

Comment: Unless you have some incredibly high level of encryption or the server you're ssh'ing into has a high load, it's probably not the ssh part of the equation. It's usually a bandwidth and/or latency issue.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12977879/252489

Comment: @Gowtham so i can use: ssh -X -C user@hostname ?

Comment: For background reading on `-no-remote`, please check https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1033721

In addition, `gfx.xrender.enabled = true` is also required (by Eric McAlvin in the lower part of this page, direct link is https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/557920/46274 )

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The default ssh settings make for a pretty slow connection. Try the following instead:

```
ssh -YC4c arcfour,blowfish-cbc user@hostname firefox -no-remote
```

The options used are:

```
-Y      Enables trusted X11 forwarding.  Trusted X11 forwardings are not
         subjected to the X11 SECURITY extension controls.
 -C      Requests compression of all data (including stdin, stdout,
         stderr, and data for forwarded X11 and TCP connections).  The
         compression algorithm is the same used by gzip(1), and the
         “level” can be controlled by the CompressionLevel option for pro‐
         tocol version 1.  Compression is desirable on modem lines and
         other slow connections, but will only slow down things on fast
         networks.  The default value can be set on a host-by-host basis
         in the configuration files; see the Compression option.
 -4      Forces ssh to use IPv4 addresses only.
 -c cipher_spec
         Selects the cipher specification for encrypting the session.

         For protocol version 2, cipher_spec is a comma-separated list of
         ciphers listed in order of preference.  See the Ciphers keyword
         in ssh_config(5) for more information.
```

The main point here is to use a different encryption cypher, in this case arcfour which is faster than the default, and to compress the data being transferred.

---

NOTE: I am very, very far from an expert on this. The command above is what I use after finding it on a blog post somewhere and I have noticed a huge improvement in speed. I am sure the various commenters below know what they're talking about and that these encryption cyphers might not be the best ones. It is very likely that the only bit of this answer that is truly relevant is using the `-C` switch to compress the data being transferred.

Comment: and there is other encryption cypher?

Comment: @AntonioBalduzzi yes, see the `Ciphers` keyword in `man 5 ssh_config`. I found that this specific setting works very well for me when launching remote firefox instances.

Comment: Actually by changing the encryption settings you can improve the _throughput_ of the connection, but that will have almost no influence on the _latency_ which is what makes the X-over-ssh connection so slow... Or said otherwise: you can achieve to transfer a file faster, but the time it takes to start transferring will not change (almost). That is the problem of the X-protocol, it involves a lot of messages and acknowledgements between the client and the server, so over internet the few milliseconds latency get multiplied many times until you can see a button change its status for instance.

Comment: Is `-4` (IPv4) really relevant here?

Comment: The `arcfour" cipher is deprecated, btw.

Comment: Compression helps, but doesn't work miracles. Firefox is very demanding. Changing the cipher is unlikely to make a difference unless one of the sides is very very limited in CPU time: with high-end devices such as smartphones and PCs, encryption/decryption time is negligible compared to network latency and bandwidth.

Comment: The ciphers suggested are the *wrong* way to go. As Gilles says, the majority of devices these days will have no problem at all with the default AES-CTR: it is very fast, *especially* if the hardware used has the AES instruction set. RC4 is weak and being phased out across the net, and Blowfish-CBC may not necessarily be faster than AES-CTR anyway.

Comment: Could you give some explanation how will `-Y` help?

Comment: @Ariel to be honest, I'm just parroting what I read in some random blog post. All I know is that using that command greatly speeded up my X ssh connections so I posted it here. Perhaps the only difference was the compression.

Comment: @Cornstalks probably not, see the note I added to my answer.

Comment: @Gilles all I know is that using this command as opposed to plain `ssh -X`, made a _huge_ difference specifically when running firefox remotely. I had the exact same issue as the OP and this rendered it possible where it was simply not so before.

Comment: @Reid as I said to the other commenters, I do not pretend to be an expert or even really know what I'm talking about here. All I know is that this speeded up my remote firefox sessions immensely.

Comment: @terdon `-C` probably helps significantly, but I don't expect changing the cipher to make a visible difference in this scenario. `-4` has no impact on performance and I don't think `-Y` does either.

Comment: I just changed my command line from `-X` to `-XC` and it has made a massive difference. I'd estimate some UI operations around 50 times faster.

Comment: (Oh, now it turns out that press E is equivalent to hitting backspace... so it's actually totally unusable anyway.)

Comment: Huge difference in speed!!!..

Comment: This helped me a bit but it was still too slow to use even after enabling gfx.xrender.enabled=true in about:config.  I tried the x2go solution https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/187420/162453 and it worked so much better I wouldn't bother with this.

Comment: I've found that the piece of this that actually helped the most for my system was the -Y part. Liclipse over the network since I moved from Ubuntu to Artix linux has been extremely slow and takes forever to redraw the screen. Putting the entire -XYC4c command in really helped. But even just -XY completely fixed the performance issues. It seems like this may be different on different distros of linux, and some may be more paranoid about X security than others. Using just -XC alone did not fix the performance issues completely, and was a more minor improvement.

Comment: **DO NOT USE -Y UNLESS YOU ABSOLUTELY KNOW WHAT THIS MEANS, UNDERSTAND THE RISKS AND `-X` IS NOT WORKING**

Comment: @symcbean there is no need to yell.

Answer (score 41):

One of the biggest issues when launching some X-client remotely is the X-protocol, not so much the ssh overhead!
The X-protocol requires a lot of ping-pong'ing between the client and the server which absolutely kills performance in the case of remote applications.

Try something like "x2go" (which also goes over ssh with default setups) in you will notice that firefox "flies" in comparison!

Several distributions provide the x2go packages out of the box, for instance Debian testing, or in Stable-Backports. But if not,
see http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/download:start , they provide prebuilt binary packages/repositories for many distributions. You should install x2goclient (on the computer where you want to interact with firefox) and x2goserver (in the computer where firefox should be running), you can then configure your sessions for single X applications of for full desktop views etc. The connection itself happens over ssh. It's a really wonderful tool :)

To use it, you run "x2goclient", it starts a GUI where you can create a new session: you provide the dns name of the server, port, ssh data, etc and then you select the "session type", ie, if you want a full remote KDE or GNOME desktop for instance, or just a "single application" and there you enter "firefox".

Comment: how i can try x2go? the command

Comment: There seems to be no `x2goserver` package on Debian (or Ubuntu). Also, can this be configured to allow tunneling? For example, I use machineX but I can only ssh to it via machineY. Could x2go deal with that?

Comment: @terdon you are right, i checked just the client. But you can just add the x2go repository (see the link http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/download:start) and the server is there. I don't know why only the client is in Debian.

Tunneling: for sure it is possible, but never tried it. I'd expect it should be enough to just configure ssh in `~/.ssh/config` and use the right (tunneled) hostname in your x2go session.

Comment: @terdon: there is a "Use proxy server for SSH connection" (ssh/http) option in the x2go session configuration. So that should do the trick also!

Comment: This seems interesting, I'll play with it some more. So far I can confirm that configuring the tunnel in `.ssh/config` is not enough. I have it setup so that `ssh machineB` actually runs via a tunnel through `machineA` but x2go does not seem to see it.

Comment: This is usually the first topic/link i land on when searching about the slowness, to see if there's any recent finding/improvement. Felt it necessary to state here this is only an issue with FireFox for me. Brave, Chrome etc all work fine and are pretty snappy. So this answer trying to state a truism that things over ssh are inherently slow etc is pretty useless.

Comment: @ustulation well, it may be that Firefox is suboptimally using the X-protocol when it comes to mouse handling and screen redrawing etc, compared to how it can be done oor how Chrome does it. I never said that "things over ssh are inherently slow", please re-read.

Comment: @Ariel Sure, might have extrapolated a bit, but the gist of what you are saying (1st para of answer) is X-Protocol's traffic over remote connection (which for OP happens to be ssh, so not a completely unfounded extrapolation) is slow and so on. Wanted to highlight that this is not true (or as true) for other browsers, so that alone cannot be a factor. That factor is more or less a truism and an answer for "why's anything X or GUI slow over ssh/remote". The question specifically asks about 1 browser & such an answer's not useful unless it demonstrates that many other browsers suffer similarly.

Answer (score 29):

I have much better experience in using an `ssh` tunnel to route traffic through another machine. It's very easy to set up since you have ssh access anyway. In a terminal on your computer, type

```
ssh -vv -ND 8080 user@yourserver
```

Keep this window open and watch it delivering some verbose messages about the data flowing through the tunnel.

In `firefox`, go to Preferences -> Advanced -> Network -> Connection: Settings.

Select *Manual proxy configuration* and add a `SOCKS v5` proxy:

```
 SOCKS Host:   localhost    Port 8080
```

Check your new IP by navigating to e.g. http://whatismyipaddress.com/.

You can use a firefox add-on like *foxy proxy* to dynamically switch proxies.

Comment: Upvoted, this a very valid alternative to using NX-based compression (x2go etc), much more useful than fiddling with ssh encryption settings :)

Comment: I used always ssh -L 8080:localhost:8080, but liked the -ND option but not sure why you used Dinamic instead or Remote or Listen. By the way, using proxy it's much better than use -X, but, I think the better way is to use VNC if you need more X programs and not just Firefox.

Comment: easy to setup and works efficiently!

Answer (score 16):

I know this post is super old, but this has helped me overcome Firefox over SSH slowness by setting the following in `about:config`

```
gfx.xrender.enabled = true
```

**Note:** Starting in Firefox 47, the default became False.

Comment: works on centos7, firefox 68.5

Comment: This should be the top comment, accepted answer. Actually solves the problem unlike the other nonsense about ssh ciphers and http pipelining! Thanks!

Comment: It worked for me and then it seemed to stop working (speeding things up) without me so much as closing the browser. I did, however, close the `x2go` client and reopen it.  `gfx.xrender.enabled` remained `true`.

Comment: @James Truly. This problem is specific to Firefox, at least not happening on the other X11 programs I've tried, so the other answers on communication channels are not relevant to this question anyway.

Comment: Worked on centos7, firefox 78,5.  Thanks

Comment: !!! This should be the top answer.  The question was why is Firefox so slow over X11-ssh forwarding?  There are other answers about how to speed up X11 or how to speed up ssh, etc.  But there is a specifically a problem with FIREFOX over X11-ssh forwarding (other apps work fine) and this answer fixes that problem.

Comment: This option is no longer there in firefox 115 which is now the default debian stable. Debian stable is usually the oldest version in use anywhere, so it's probably not a viable solution.

Answer (score 3):

X11 is an outdated protocol. For example if a software writes the letter "A" over and over into the same spot it will be retransmitted over and over again. A lot of modern GUIs tend to redraw stuff which didn't change and X11 will happily retransmit every atomic screen-output. In other words, it does not transmit pixels but commands. This is the opposite how VNC and Teamviewer are working which basically are transfering pixels. This also leads to a partially synchronous operation where one command has to wait for another command to finish.

SSH uses a ton of CPU power and doesn't multithread. For example my server is running SSH on a single core at 100% but this only equals to around 20MByte/s of uncompressed data and around 5MByte/s of compressed data for X11.

Firefox is highly X11 unfriendly. It rarelly uses commands - which X11 could handle efficiently - but mostly small and badly compressable bitmaps which it packs into X11 bitplane operations. Combining two things which should never come close anyway.
Worst case: Any small animation. Even a 64x64 pixel animated GIF can literally freeze your firefox connection.

That said lets dive deeper.

On a highspeed line - e.g. 100Mbit or higher - compression is usually more of a burden than a bone. Your milage may vary. Try ssh with "-C". With SSH2 there is no more manual selection of compression level, you stuck with something comparable to "gzip -3" or have to do some trickery tunneling. It might be possible to get faster compression using the pretty fast "lzop -1" or better compression using "xz -9e". I played around with "lzop -1" some ten years ago and results where unimpressive.

The speed of your crypto stuff depends a lot on your CPU. See https://possiblelossofprecision.net/?p=2255 for a easy way to check which cypher runs fastest on your system. Expect two times of speed between fastest and slowest. Though over the last 20 years I have never seen a slow cypher as standard, the cypher usually are defaulting to something close to the fastest.

Now here is you best bet: Disable Hardware-Acceleration in Firefox. This is rarelly required as Firefox disables it anyway over Network but in some circumstances it fails to do so and thats where Firefox gets really, really, really slow.

This is all one can say about Firefox, SSH and X11. If this doesn't do the trick try something else:

Run X11 without SSH by doing something like this on the X11-Server

```
startx -- -listen tcp &
sleep 5
export DISPLAY=:0
xhost +yourx11client +yourx11client.local
```

and on the X11-client:

```
export DISPLAY=yourx11server:0
```

Hint, X11 server and client nominations are "reversed". The server is the display, the client is running the application.

This will easily speed up Firefox ten times. Though some pages will still make it very sluggish and unresponsive, e.g. videos.

An even more drastic step: Drop X11 as a network protocol, use VNC. Either by using a remote screen or a fully virtualized VNC session:

```
vncserver :1 -name VNC1 -geometry 1024x768 -depth 15
```

and in $HOME/.vnc/xstartup something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
unset SESSION_MANAGER
exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
xterm -geometry 80x30
```

I highly suggest using the xsetroot command as default X11 background looks horrible and is hard to compress.

Connect with any VNC-Client you like.

I have been able to watch TV and play games over this kind of VNC connection. You can even run multiple vncservers for multiple users at once.

This is by far the most responsive remote system.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox so slow over SSH because newer builds of firefox allow multiple instances.If you have bandwidth problems, use a light browser like dillo and you willl not even notice the connection speed.

Comment: This answer is from [a post on ArchLinux forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=64751#p64751).

Comment: this has nothing to do with the issue - the issue is not the browser but the X11 remote protocol

Answer (score 0):

You have to experiment to see what helps with your specific bottlenecks.

For me, enabling compression (`-C`) improved responsiveness from unusable to just noticable lag.

Choice of cipher can have an impact too, contrary to what some people said. You can find people sharing benchmarks online, but don't presume that your results will be the same. Which cipher is best for you is hardware dependent. For me my default cipher (chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com) was already tied for the fastest one.

I wrote a quick script to benchmark relevant ciphers under somewhat realistic conditions. Explanations in the comments:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

# Ciphers available to you depends on the intersection of ciphers compiled 
# into your client and the ciphers compiled into your host.
# Should be manually copied from "Ciphers:" section in your `man ssh_config`
# The script will try all ciphers specified here and will gracefully skip
# ciphers unavailable in the host.
#ciphers=""
# Example:
ciphers="3des-cbc aes128-cbc aes192-cbc aes256-cbc aes128-ctr aes192-ctr aes256-ctr aes128-gcm@openssh.com aes256-gcm@openssh.com chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com"

tmp_file=tmp.bin

# Recommend to use an identity file without a passphrase.
# That way you won't have to retype the password at each iteration.
ssh_identity_file=~/.ssh/tmp_id_no_passphrase

ssh_host="user@host"

# Size of test file, before encryption.
test_file_size_megabytes=8

# Only create test file if it doesn't yet exists.
# Doesn't check if relevant variables changed, so you'll have to delete
# the $tmp_file to regenerate it.
if test ! -f $tmp_file; then
  echo "Creating random data file" \
    "(size $test_file_size_megabytes MB): $tmp_file"

  # Not the same format as the ssh ciphers.
  # Can be left as is, unless this cipher is not supported by your openssl.
  tmp_file_cipher=aes-128-cbc

  # The purpose of encrypting the $tmp_file is to make it uncompressable.
  # I do not know if that is a concern in this scenario,
  # but better safe than sorry.

  dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=$test_file_size_megabytes \
    | openssl enc -$tmp_file_cipher -pass pass:123 \
    > $tmp_file
fi

for cipher in $ciphers ; do
  # Benchmark each $cipher multiple times
  for i in 1 2 3 ; do
    echo
    echo "Cipher: $cipher (try $i)"
    # Time piping the $tmp_file via SSH to $ssh_host using $cipher.
    # At destination received data is discarded.
    cat $tmp_file \
      | /usr/bin/time -p \
      ssh -i $ssh_identity_file -c "$cipher" $ssh_host 'cat > /dev/null'
  done
done

# Sample output:

# Creating random data file (size 8 MB): tmp.bin
# *** WARNING : deprecated key derivation used.                                   Using -iter or -pbkdf2 would be better.                                         8+0 records in
# 8+0 records out
# 8388608 bytes (8.4 MB, 8.0 MiB) copied, 0.0567188 s, 148 MB/s

## [redacted]

# Cipher: aes256-cbc (try 3)
# Unable to negotiate with 192.168.99.99 port 22: no matching cipher found. Their offer: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
# real 0.12
# user 0.03
# sys 0.03

# Cipher: aes128-ctr (try 1)
# real 9.68
# user 0.28
# sys 0.51

# Cipher: aes128-ctr (try 2)
# real 10.85
# user 0.26
# sys 0.29

## [redacted]
```

You can choose to test with an SSH connection where the client and host are the same machine, or you can test in a more realistic scenario, where the host is the machine you're doing the X11 forwarding from, which should be more useful, because the performance not only depends on the client's performance deciphering, but also the host's.

Testing with a remote machine can have the disadvantage of introducing noise if the throughput of your internet connection changes in the course of the benchmark. In that case, might want to bump up the number of times each cipher is tested.

Answer (score 0):

Also we got a good solution with  Xvfb (X virtual framebuffer)

on remote server as admin (Centos 7 example)

```
yum install Xvfb xauth x11vnc firefox
```

on remote server as normal user

```
Xvfb :1 &
x11vnc -display :1 --localhost &
export DISPLAY=:1
firefox
```

on local computer:

```
vncviewer -via www.example.com 127.0.0.1
```

### Another solution is xpra

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xpra#Run_applications_in_a_persistent_xpra_server_on_the_remote_host

on server:

```
xpra start :100
DISPLAY=:100 firefox
```

on client:

```
  xpra attach --ssh="ssh" ssh:user@serverhost:100
```

Answer (score -2):

Another thing that will improve your browsing over ssh is to enable pipelining in Firefox. Open <kbd>about:config</kbd> and change <kbd>network.http.pipelining</kbd> to true.

Comment: That option should make the loading of webpages faster, but is completely unrelated to the fact that the browser is running over an SSH tunnel or not. Anyways, beware of the "but's" when you touch advanced options... see http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.pipelining

Comment: In my experience browsing over ssh gets slow and pipelining requests is a big help since otherwise any given request has to wait for previous ones which may or may not complete in a timely manner if at all. I also combine this with ssh multiplexing. It makes a noticeable difference. Turning off pipelining goes back to being unbearably slow in my case.