# X Window Over network

Tags: networking, x11, bandwidth

What makes X Window or X11 protocol use a lot of bandwidth when used over a network (LTSP, etc.)? I've tried to read some docs but I can't find the answer

Comment: What i want to know does it affected by its size of the information sent/received, or because of the avg. amount of packet per second.

Comment: I am not sure I really understand your question then. Are you wondering if "a lot of bandwidth" is used by many packets of small size (and correspondingly more control overhead) or few but huge packets? AFAIK the first is the case. Can you go into detail what exactly you where looking for or what is the deeper reason you want to understand this better?

Comment: I am looking for the reason why it use a lot of bandwidth, is it because of the amount of packets sent and the size of the packet itself? Or maybe something else? I want to know it for a research matters

Comment: You could try [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to analyze the packet traffic. I am sure wireshark also offers some statistics.

Answer (score 0):

X should run fine in a LAN environment but will impact the traffic when using multiple clients. This also depends on the applications, especially when image transfer is involved. Also, the X protocol does not necessarily cope with flaky connections, e.g. mobile connections or some wifi networks. It was not designed to be robust under these circumstances. If you try to improve performance I would recommend [x2go](http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php) which might also work with LTSP (https://lizards.opensuse.org/2012/09/27/run-x2go-thin-client-using-kiwi-ltsp/). Also see [How to speed up X over SSH on a slow network connection?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21016/how-to-speed-up-x-over-ssh-on-a-slow-network-connection) for some hints.

Comment: Well, this is not the really answer I need. Thanks anyway